# MonoGame: prevent command prompt in windows?

Tags: c#, monogame

Is there a way to prevent the command prompt from opening in windows when launching the game (via double clicking)?

Comment: by dosbox you mean the black window similar to "command prompt", right? since dosbox is name of another application which seems to be completely unrelated to the topic!

Comment: Yes, by dosbox, I mean the command prompt. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Have you tried building your application in release mode?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using Visual Studio 2010.

Right click on your project (not solution), go to the "Application" tab, under "Output type" change that to "Windows Application"

This is what I do when I want to see a command prompt when running an XNA application.

Comment: Thanks Luis, this did the trick. For those who use MonoDevelop, its equivalent is Executable with GUI

Comment: @void_null, Mark as answer :)